# I want to fill background color from df.shape returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill background color from df.shape returns this color #A9D08E from second row.
like this image
[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Beexprss\Desktop\python\ar.xlsx')

def color_cells(val):
    if val == df.shape or val >= 1:
        return 'background-color: #A9D08E'
    else:
        return ''

styled_df = df.style.applymap(color_cells)
styled_df
```

I typed above code but result is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide example data to debug it?

Comment: AWB/COD Amount AWB/Delivery Charges AWB/Other Cost AWB/Cash by first mile AWB/Cash by last mile AR 0.5% Deducted
19900 1500   21400  
49500 3500   53000  
35000 3500   38500  
36000 3500   39500  
19000 3500   22500  
8000 4000   12000  
25500 4000   29500  
30000 4000   34000  
19800 4000   23800  
17400 3000   20400  
14000 4000   18000  
30000 3500   33500  


there is my data, but I just want to fill background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background_color = '#A9D08E'
styled_df = df.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': background_color})
```

Comment: thank you .
this is exactly what I want to do.